# Get custom value after paypal successful paying

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, paypal

When somenone starts a paypal paying I send a custom value with the transaction. But after the success of the paying on the /success route, the server can only get the payerId and paymentId. **So my question is, how do I get the custom value after the success of the payment?**

Comment: how did you pass the custom value? through `custom` I'm assuming? If so you can use PDT or IPN to get the `custom` var back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the custom variable why would you want it to return, simply store it and append after the call has been made. It would be a security breach to set a variable inside a return call from outsource api